# Mysql inner join or left join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 1 table products and I would like to extract price of products with type A and B. I try to use INNER JOIN but it returns duplicate record. How can I do this?

```
 id   |   Price    |     Date    |   Type   |   Size  |
-------------------------------------------------------
 1    |   1,00     |  01/11/2010 |     A    |   7,00  |
 2    |   2,50     |  02/11/2010 |     A    |   8,00  |
 3    |   2,50     |  03/11/2010 |     A    |   9,00  |
 4    |   3,00     |  02/11/2010 |     A    |  10,00  |
 5    |   4,00     |  03/11/2010 |     A    |  11,00  |
 6    |   4,00     |  03/11/2010 |     A    |  12,00  |
 7    |   5,00     |  03/11/2010 |     A    |  13,00  |
 8    |   5,00     |  03/11/2010 |     A    |  14,00  |
 9    |   6,00     |  03/11/2010 |     A    |  15,00  |
10    |   7,00     |  03/11/2010 |     A    |  16,00  |
11    |   1,00     |  03/11/2010 |     B    |  17,00  |
12    |   2,50     |  03/11/2010 |     B    |  18,00  |
13    |   3,00     |  03/11/2010 |     B    |  19,00  |
14    |   3,00     |  03/11/2010 |     B    |  20,00  |
15    |   5,00     |  03/11/2010 |     B    |  21,00  |
16    |   6,00     |  03/11/2010 |     B    |  22,00  |
17    |   7,00     |  03/11/2010 |     B    |  23,00  |
18    |   7,00     |  03/11/2010 |     B    |  24,00  |
```

And I would like to build a table like this:

```
 Price    |     Date    |   Size A |   Size B  |
-------------------------------------------------------
 1,00     |  01/11/2010 |    7,00  |   17,00   |
 2,50     |  02/11/2010 |    8,00  |           |
 2,50     |  03/11/2010 |    9,00  |   18,00   |
 3,00     |  02/11/2010 |   10,00  |   19,00   |
 4,00     |  03/11/2010 |   11,00  |           |
 4,00     |  04/11/2010 |   12,00  |           |
 5,00     |  03/11/2010 |   13,00  |   21,00   |
 5,00     |  04/11/2010 |   14,00  |           |
 6,00     |  05/11/2010 |   15,00  |           |
 7,00     |  06/11/2010 |   16,00  |   23,00   |
```

How can I do that in one query?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Provide proper table definitions along with your query attempt

Answer (score 0):

```
select price, 
       date, 
       sum(case when `type` = 'A' then size else 0 end) as SizeA,
       sum(case when `type` = 'B' then size else 0 end) as SizeB
from products
group by price, date
order by price, date
```

Group by the `date` to get the data for each date. To get the other columns you need to use aggregate functions like `sum()`.

If you really need the `null` values you can do:

```
case when sum(`type` = 'A') = 0 
     then null 
     else sum(case when `type` = 'A' then size end)
end
```

Comment: I'm sure you're right, but maybe add an explanation here.

Comment: also think you need to group by the price AND Date (does not make sense per their data), but their data is all the same date, but multiple returned rows APPEARS based on price too.

Comment: It returns only 3 rows:
 Price    |     Date    |   Size A |   Size B  |
-------------------------------------------------------
 1,00     |  01/11/2010 |    0    |       0       |
 2,00     |  02/11/2010 |    0    |                |
 1,00     |  03/11/2010 |    0    |       0       |

You're right DRapp I have to filter by date and price